# Como consigo sacar RAW XML de este script?

Tags: php, xml

Estoy usando este script que envia informacion a un servidor, y este responde con XML. El resultado lo paso a otro script mediante una variable. Como consigo sacar XML raw, sin filtrarlo ?

```html
function lafuncion($dato1,$dato2)
{
$this->connect("La direccion");
  //get the output
  $xmlstr=$this->getOutput();
  if($xmlstr=='')
  {
   $this->errors[]='No output.';
   return false;
  }
  //disconnect
  $this->disconnect();

  //get the output xml as an array using simple xml
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

  if($xml->result->status==1)
  {
   
   $result['status']=$xml->result->status;
   $result['statusmsg']=$xml->result->statusmsg;
   $result['ip']=$xml->result->options->ip;
   return $result;
  }
  else
  {
   $this->errors[]=$xml->result->statusmsg;
   return false;
  }
 }
```

Comment: No entiendo tu necesidad, el XML está en `$xmlstr`. ¿Puedes desarrollar un poco más?

Comment: @Solrac Al intentar pasar $xmlstr a otro script php solo me aparece " Array() ".      La idea como tal es recibir la respuesta en XML en este script, y pasarlo a otro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el método `asXML()` para obtener un `string`:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$string = $xml->asXML();
```

En lo personal me gusta mas usar la clase `DOMDocument` en lugar de `SimpleXML`:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xmlstr);
$string = $doc->saveXML();
```

Comment: Gracias por responder Solrac. El problema al usar el método asXML() es que solo me devuelve el mensaje de que se a realizado con exito, pero no devuelve mas datos. Y al usar DOMDocument devuelve " Notice: Trying to get property of non-object " y despues solo Array ( [0] => ) .

Comment: Al final enredando un poco lo e conseguido, gracias :)